# wxMaxima transform trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, maxima, wxmaxima

I got a equation in the following form

```
f(t) = 2*cos(t) + 3*sin(t)
```

and I want to reduce it to something like

```
f(t) = (9 + 4)^(1/2) * cos(t - atan(3/2))
```

None of the trigonometric simplify functions seems to work. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What is `sen(t)` ?

Comment: I think you mean `sin(t)` instead of `sen(t)`. Note the inverse tangent is `atan` or `atan2` instead of `arctg`. Also functions are defined by `:=` instead of `=`, but anyway Maxima prefers to work on expressions, so you might say `e: 2*cos(t) + 3*sin(t);` and go from there. You can get the result you want by walking through the solution of `a*cos(t - b) = 2*cos(t) + 3*sin(t)` step by step, but I don't know a single function which does it all at once. I can help with that if you want. For further discussion, try the mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: You are right @RobertDodier, I meant sin(t) and just edited it. I think I got the step by step way, but thank you very much, I will try the mailing list